# Building animations into a subclass of UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit

I've created a table view that I really like - it plays some nice animations in the delegate function `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`.

The trouble is, I can't find a way to duplicate that behavior elsewhere in my codebase without copy and pasting the code inside the delegate function and violating DRY. I want to be able to adjust the animation parameters of all the tableviews in my project from one place.

1. First I tried to write a subclass of `UITableView`, but that's no good because the animations are specified in a delegate function. You could make the subclass its own delegate and define the behavior you want, but then none of its other delegate functions are available to its containing view.
2. I considered writing a protocol that inherits from `UITableViewDelegate`, but then you would have to reimplement every tableview delegate function in the protocol even though only one of them is different.
3. I thought about trying to swizzle the willDisplayCell function, but I'm not sure that would work, and I really don't want to mess with swizzling if I stay away from it.

How can I pull something like this off? Both in this very specific case, and in the more general OOP sense of wanting to provide default behavior for a delegate function without having to set the class as its own delegate?

Edit:  It's not something that you can really take a picture of, but nonetheless screenshot as requested.
[image]

Comment: Please put the screen sort what you want.

Comment: I'm not sure if a screenshot will help much, but hopefully it'll make what I'm trying to do more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not subclass UITableView, nor swizzle, or extend the delegate protocol.

What I would do is to write a class that implements and wraps the delegate methods. This class could have it's own delegate, but I'd rather give it closures to call.

```
class TableViewDelegate: UITableViewDeleagte {
    var willDisplayCell: ((UITableView, UITableViewCell, IndexPath) -> Void)?
    let animator: Animator
    weak var tableView: UITableView? {
        didSet {
            tableView?.delegate = self
        }
    }
    init(tableView: UITableView, animator: Animator) {
        self.animator = animator
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UItableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath ) {
        animator.animate(cell)
        willDisplayCell?(tableView, cell, indexPath)
    }
}
```

---

a complete example:

```
protocol AnimatorType {
    func animate(view: UIView)
}


class Animator: AnimatorType {
    func animate(view: UIView) {
        view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -30, y: 0)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            view.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        })
    }
}

class TableViewDataSource:NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {

    let data = Array(0 ..< 30).map{ $0 * $0 }
    init(tableView: UITableView) {
        self.tableView = tableView
        super.init()
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    weak var tableView: UITableView?

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell1", for: indexPath)
        let v = data[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(v)"

        return cell
    }

    func object(at indexPath: IndexPath)  -> Int{
        return self.data[indexPath.row]
    }
}


class TableViewDelegate:NSObject, UITableViewDelegate {

    var willDisplayCell: ((UITableView, UITableViewCell, IndexPath) -> Void)?
    var didSelectCell: ((UITableView, IndexPath) -> Void)?

    let animator: AnimatorType
    weak var tableView: UITableView?

    init(tableView: UITableView, animator: AnimatorType) {
        self.tableView = tableView
        self.animator = animator
        super.init()
        tableView.delegate = self

    }

    private var highestIndexPath = IndexPath(row: -1, section: 0)

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath ) {
        if indexPath.row > highestIndexPath.row {
            animator.animate(view: cell)
            highestIndexPath = indexPath

        }
        willDisplayCell?(tableView, cell, indexPath)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        didSelectCell?(tableView, indexPath)
    }
}


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var tableViewDataSource: TableViewDataSource?
    var tableViewDelegate: TableViewDelegate?
    let animator = Animator()

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableViewDataSource = TableViewDataSource(tableView: tableView)
        self.tableViewDelegate = TableViewDelegate(tableView: tableView, animator: animator)

        self.tableViewDelegate?.didSelectCell = {
            [weak self] tableView, indexPath in
            guard let `self` = self else { return }
            print("selected: \(self.tableViewDataSource!.object(at: indexPath))")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is what I'll go with. Recasting the protocol as a class so it can be inherited is very clever. I'm going to steal your idea to make the animator a variable instead of defining it outright too. You've been doing this for awhile haven't you?

Comment: Well, my professional iOS developer career started as an iPhoneOS developer career. But first of all this code respects the SOLID principles – which I follow for every project I write. Check them out!

Comment: BTW: there shouldn't be much need to subclass `TableViewDelegate`, as it would be highly configurable and follows the [*Composition-over-Inheritance*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) paradigm. To gain the highest flexibility and reusability `Animator` would be a protocol.

Comment: Yeah, I've implemented it already quickly realized I'll never need to subclass it. This general principal is going to be great to have in my tool belt. I'll definitely check out those links and google SOLID tomorrow.

Comment: @vikingsegundo Over the course of about a month this one answer has completely changed the way I design software now. I'm really grateful that you took the time to point me to those other resources and flesh out the example you provided!

Answer (score 1):

Create `UIViewController` Subclass all your animated tableViews inherit from:

```
class BaseAnimatedTableViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate  {
    var tableView: UITableView!  

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView = UITableView
        //setupTableView
        tableView.delegatge = self
    }  
    //override delegate methods, that all subclasses should share
}
```

and subclass it for each animated tableView:

```
class AnimatedTableView1: BaseAnimatedTableViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
       ...
}

class AnimatedTableView2: BaseAnimatedTableViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
       ...
}
```

You can certainly also subclass `UITableViewController` instead of `UIViewController`.

Comment: So the trick is encapsulating the delegate methods in a class that can be subclassed to get inheritance. Thank you! I'm going to go with vikingosegundo's answer because it doesn't require making the view into a controller, but yours is just as good!